# Call to a member function on null in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4

In my Symfony project I wrote a query with Doctrine to return one specific result which I will display in my custom array.

I constantly get an error:

> Call to a member function getSeats() on null

I tried a bunch of things..

```
 return $this->createQueryBuilder("e")
        ->where('e.userId =:userId')
        ->setParameter('userId', $user)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getOneOrNullResult();
```

And in my array..

```
$reports = [
            'id' => $report['id'],
             ....
            'seats' => is_null($seats->getSeats()) ? 0 : $seats->getSeats()
        ];
```

I tought the best way to do it is by ternary operator but no luck/

My entity object:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", options={"default":0})
 */
protected $seats;
```

Comment: You are binding the wrong parameter, the parameter is called `userId`, not `user`, that's why it's always returning null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `is_null` is correct, however you need to check whether the object itself is null:

```
'seats' => is_null($seats) ? 0 : $seats->getSeats()
```